# Bought App from Google Play has to be Repurchased on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-store-apps, google-play-services, windows-10

There is really no correct place to ask this question, so I hope someone here can answer me.

If I already bought an app through Google Play, do I have to repurchase it if I want it on my Windows 10 computer (to synch between Android phone and computer)?

I certainly seems that way. I am logged in with the correct gmail account on both devices. I also tried pressing the price button in the Windows 10 store, but it does ask for my credit details. Also, no apps appear under under the "Bought" menu.

I would appreciate any help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently apps on the Windows Store are apps that are for or run on Windows 10, the Google Play store is for apps under that store and ecosystem and an app on one store would have to be purchased from the other as well if want it on Android Phone and Windows 10 PC at the moment